# Why Is There The Term 1/m In Backpropagation

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, backpropagation, math, derivative

In backpropagation the gradients are used to update the weights using the formula
$$w = w - \alpha \frac{dL}{dw}$$
and the loss gradient w.r.t. weights is
$$\frac{dL}{dw} = \frac{dL}{dz} \frac{dz}{dw} = (\frac{dL}{da} \frac{da}{dz} \frac{1}{m}) \frac{dz}{dw} $$

Why is the there the $\frac{1}{m}$ term? Does batch size matter and what if it's 1?

Comment: could you post a link to the book/blogpost from which you got the formula? m should be just the total amount of weights, but the notation is not consistent across literature so to be sure I should check from your source.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that m is the number of features in the last layer's output. Here's the video link https://youtu.be/yXcQ4B-YSjQ?list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Ec-XTbcX1uRg2_u4xOEky0&t=780 but he writes it in an abbreviated way